# Find Number of 0's at end of integer using POWER QUERY Power Bi

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

I wanted to find out the number of 0's at end of integer.
Eg for 2020 it should count 1
for 2000 it should count 3
for 3010000 it should count 4

I have no idea to do it without counting all the zeros and not just the ending ones!

someone please help :)

Comment: I need this done on PowerBI QUERY EDITOR I tried creating a custom column

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Power Query Editor** and add a **Custom Colum** with this below code-

```
if Number.Mod([number],100000) = 0 then 5
else if Number.Mod([number],10000) = 0 then 4
else if Number.Mod([number],1000) = 0 then 3
else if Number.Mod([number],100) = 0 then 2
else if Number.Mod([number],10) = 0 then 1
else 0
```

> Considered highst possibility of trailing 0 is 5. You can add more if/else case following the above logic if you predict more numbers of consecutive 0 at the end.

Here is sample output using above logic-

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Take advantage of the fact, that text "00123" converted to number will be 2 characters shorter.

```
= let
TxtRev = Text.Reverse(Number.ToText([num]))&"1", /*convert to text and reverse, add 1 to handle num being 0*/
TxtNoZeroes = Number.ToText(Number.FromText(TxtRev)) /*convert to number to remove starting zeroes and then back to text*/
in 
Text.Length(TxtRev)-Text.Length(TxtNoZeroes) /*compare length of original value with length without zeroes*/
```

[image]

This will work for any number of trailing zeroes (up to Int64 capacity of course, minus space for `&"1"`). Assuming that the column is of number type; if it's a text then just remove `Number.ToText` in `TxtRev`. If you have negative numbers or decimals, replace characters not being a digit after converting to text. For initial number being 0 it shows 1, but if it should show 0 just remove `&"1"`.

Comment: hey AdamL thank you for this! can I paste this directly in the Custom Column? how can I apply this (I'm still new to Powebi Query)

Comment: @Girl007 Yes, you can paste it in 'Add Column' > 'Custom Column' > 'Custom column formula'. Just replace [num] with your column name.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as general string manipulation:

```
= Text.Length(Text.From([number])) - Text.Length(Text.TrimEnd(Text.From(number]), "0"))
```

We convert the column to string, strip of the zeroes, count take that away from the total length, giving you the amount of stripped zeroes.

*Edit: I messed up my first answer, this one should in fact be correct*

Comment: This will return count of all zeros in the value which is not the requirement. OP's requirement is to count Trailing consecutive zeros. Its returning 5 for 3010000 where as OP wants 4.

Comment: Oh my, you're right. I completely misread the question. I updated my answer